React-query sometimes render with no uses value and i don't know why
I try to make infinite scroll. And i found out sometime react query fetch twice. for example, it should fetch only second page, but some time fetch second and third pages. (I'll call this a bug in the future. Of course it's because I'm wrong.)
I fount out its because i try to change state inside useEffect. so i solve problems.
But still there is something weird thing when the 'bug' happend.
There is only two state in my code. one is react query data and other is state that i try to change in useEffect.
useEffect(()=>{
  setState(data);
},[data]);

Everytime react query fetch data, there should be two render(first query data is changed, second state is changed)
But when 'bug' happend there is additional one render, and that is because of "isFetching", "isFetchingNextPage", "fetchStatus". (i never uses this value)
render1
render2
In the react query docs, there should be no render when variable that are no uses are changed.

React Query will only trigger a re-render if one of the properties returned from useQuery is actually "used". This is done by using custom getters. This avoids a lot of unnecessary re-renders, e.g. because properties like isFetching or isStale might change often, but are not used in the component.

It only happen when i call fetchNextPage() twice for very short time.
So, I don't know why react query render with no uses variable when i call fetchNextPage() twice for short time.
my full code is here:
export default function ContentList() {
  const searchParams = useParams("category").getParamsToString();

  const contentsCountData = { count: 297 };

  const data = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ["contents", searchParams],
    queryFn: ({ pageParam }) => getContents(pageParam, searchParams),
    initialPageParam: 1,
    getNextPageParam: (_, __, lastPageParam, ___) => {
      if (contentsCountData !== undefined) {
        return lastPageParam + 1 > Math.ceil(contentsCountData.count / 10)
          ? null
          : lastPageParam + 1;
      }
    },
    enabled: contentsCountData !== undefined,
    notifyOnChangeProps: ["data"],
    staleTime: 5 * 1000 * 60,
    gcTime: 30 * 1000 * 60,
  });

  const alignedContentsData = data.data;

  const [contentsData, setContentsData] = useState<IContentData[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (alignedContentsData) {
      setContentsData(
        alignedContentsData.pages.map((page) => page.content).flat()
      );
    }
  }, [alignedContentsData]);

  const ref = useIntersect(() => {
    data.fetchNextPage();
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.data);
    console.log(contentsData);
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {contentsData &&
        contentsData.map((content, index) => (...)

I check out with react dev tools and make sure react query data is trigger render .
